# How to find average of values when I have rows/columns values in spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that looks like this

```
block   x-start  y-start  x-end  y-end
block1    10       10       20     20 
block2    0        0       10      10
```

etc.
the values in the above table represent rows and columns in another excel worksheet.

So for block one, I want to get the average value from row/column 10,10-20,20 in the other worksheet.   Any ideas how to do this?
Obviously I can do a manual highlight the rows/columns in question and see the average, but I have thousands of these I need to calculate and need to do it in an automated way.

Thanks for the help.
D.E.

Comment: Look at using OFFSET() - it will offset from a fixed location by #rows/#cols and size from that point by #rows/#cols   https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `OFFSET()` - it will offset from a fixed location by #rows/#cols and size from that point by #rows/#cols

[image]